# End to end encryption and OTR on Gajim

Tags: instant-messaging, off-the-record

In [Gajim](https://gajim.org/), does OTR and end to end encryption work together? Or is OTR turned off if I start end to end encryption?

Comment: Your question seems unclear, please edit it to help others with the same issue.

Comment: This is a product-specific question. Please contact their support.